# Laravel env() value null

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I'am trying to retrieve EXAMPLE_URL=www.google.com from .env in controller and everytime get null. Where is the problem because the same code works on another application. This function doesn't work after php artisan cache:clear.

Controller code

```
    $hostname = env("EXAMPLE_URL");

    dump($hostname);
```

Comment: why i need to restart my server?

Comment: try with config('EXAMPLE_URL')

Comment: it's hosted in linux server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not use `env()` outside of the config files.

Read: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration

You should add the env variable to a config file and use `config('example.url');`.

The example.php would look like:

```php
return [
    'url' => env('EXAMPLE_URL', 'https://example.com'),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use the app file as the middleman

see : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration